# SQL Server 2008 won't let me enable the 'sa' user

Tags: sql-server

I normally use the `sa` user for development, but SQL Server isn't letting me enable the account. It says:

> Cannot set a credential for principal user 'sa'

When installing it I set it up with mixed mode.

Comment: good question for the serverfault.com

Comment: its my development computer, what's the big deal? you can't access sqlserver from the outside anyhow.

Comment: the big deal is that if you use 'sa' on your dev machine, suddenly your app and its config gets deployed to production and you end up with 'sa' in production...... seen it happen a gazillion of times. DON'T DO IT ! PERIOD. :-)

Comment: I vote for changing the title to: "What options are preferable to using the `sa` account when developing for SQL Server 2008?"

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://www.techurbia.com/2009/03/cannot-set-a-credential-for-principal-sa-sql-server-20052008.html)  may be of help. But I agree with Coehoorn's statement - DON'T USE SA.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the sa account ever, even for development work.  Not only is it dangerous from a security standpoint, it can also lead to bugs popping up at deployment when you suddenly don't have permissions for something.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of SA, grant your own windows account the appropriate perms in SQL Server. Leave mixed mode off if possible, or if you must have mixed mode, disable the SA account itself.